# $state.current.name become false or true insead of keeping his name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app jhipster / angular, i have a pagination on my content. When i click to change the current page, it will do $state.transitionTo but i'm getting an error :

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: stateName.indexOf is not a function
at isRelative (angular-ui-router.js:2299)
at findState (angular-ui-router.js:2307)
at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3158)
at Product_detailController.transition (product-detail.controller.js:379)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14432), <anonymous>:4:260)
at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15485)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
at angular.js:24056
at angular.js:26824
at forEach (angular.js:322)
```

and i notice that in $state.current.self.name and $state.current.name = false and not "product-detail".

[image]

Any ideas ?

My state.js :

```
.state('product-detail-detail', {
        parent: 'entity',
        url: '/product-detail-detail?page&sort&search&prod',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'eProductApp.product_detail.detail.title'
        },
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/product-detail/product-detail-detail.html',
                controller: 'Product_detailController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        params: {
            page: {
                value: '1',
                squash: true
            },
            sort: {
                value: 'id,asc',
                squash: true
            },
            search:null,
            prod: {
                value: null,
                squash: true
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            pagingParams: ['$stateParams', 'PaginationUtil', function ($stateParams, PaginationUtil) {
                console.log($stateParams);
                return {
                    page: PaginationUtil.parsePage($stateParams.page),
                    sort: $stateParams.sort,
                    search: $stateParams.search,
                    predicate: PaginationUtil.parsePredicate($stateParams.sort),
                    ascending: PaginationUtil.parseAscending($stateParams.sort),
                    prod: $stateParams.prod
                };
            }],
            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('product_detail');
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
                return $translate.refresh();
            }]
        }
    })
```

My function in controller .js :

```
function transition() {


        $state.transitionTo($state.$current, {
            page : vm.page,
            sort : vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc'),
            search : vm.ppf,
            prod : vm.productid
        });

    }
```

Comment: So, why use transitionTo() instead of go()? You posted the $state details, opening 'current', but in your code you have $state.$current (in the transition() function), are you sure you're examining the correct part? Also, don't see indexOf() anywhere in that code, is it somewhere else that you haven't included?

Comment: when i create an entity with jhipster, the generate code use transitionTo and it works well on other page of the app for pagination. I made the same things in this page "product-detail-detail" but not work.
indexOf is in the angular code in angular-ui-router.js

Comment: Try changing the transition code to $state.$current.name see if that works.

Comment: I force to work the transitionto by setting the $state.current.name to my value. It works. But i want to know why the current state name change his name to false or true